# Pandas: nansum Series to each column of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sum a Series to each of the columns of a DataFrame, having the same behaviour of nansum: if one component is missing, return the other; if both are missing return NaN/0.

Test case:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1], [2, 2], [3, 4]])
ts = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 4])
```

Attempt 1 (gives nan when one is missing):

```
df.add(ts, axis=0)

Out[115]: 
     0    1
0  NaN  2.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  7.0  8.0
```

Attempt 2 (throws error):

```
df.add(ts, axis=0, fill_value=0)
NotImplementedError: fill_value 0 not supported.
```

Expected Output:

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  2  2
2  7  8
```

Note: I could do it by saving location of NaNs, doing the sum with NaN filled with 0 and set to NaN when both are NaN, but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Why not `fillna`? `df.fillna(0).add(ts.fillna(0), axis=0)`

Comment: In pandas 0.21, sum of all NaNs returns NaN. So if I do what you suggest, I would then have to apply a mask for the case when both dataframe and series are NaN. 

Nothing crazy, but I am just surprised pandas does not support the operation I described above and I would like to know if there's a better solution.

Comment: Yes, the feature is in the works but has not been implemented yet. Sit tight, it should be out in the next release. Until then, this is the workaround ^^^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fill_value` for anything besides `None` is still in the works, but as of now, you'll have to workaround this. Perform addition, and then compute the mask to reinstate `NaN`s where required.

```
r = df.fillna(0).add(ts.fillna(0), axis=0)

m = df.isnull().__and__(ts.isnull(), axis=0).values
v = r.values
v[m] = np.nan

r[:] = v
```

```
r
     0    1
0  1.0  2.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  7.0  8.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete solution. Is it encouraged to use .__and__ or it it more of a hack here?

Comment: @FLab It's a bit hacky but it was the only way I could specify an axis. Overloaded operators don't give you that flexibility.